# text wrapping on the gridview column

Tags: asp.net, gridview

**EDITED:**

is there a way i can use `"<BR>"` after every comma(,) ?

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sds" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings %>"
    EnableCaching="false" SelectCommand="Names_sp" SelectCommandType="storedProcedure">
</asp:SqlDataSource>



<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name(s)">
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:hyperlink id="lnk" runat="server" 
                    navigateurl='<%#Eval("Ids"%>'
                    text='<%#Eval("Names")%>'></asp:hyperlink>             
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

so the output(1 row for an example.) of the above code is in the gridview is like this:

```
Name(s)
--------------

John Doe,Jane Doe,Mike Alter,Bob Schuldz
```

so my question is:

after comma(,) make it next line instead of one line

```
Name(s)
--------------

John Doe
Jane Doe
Mike Alter
Bob Schuldz
```

Comment: Is it a common link for all names or are you expecting separate links for each name?

Comment: its a common linke for the all names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Text='<%# Eval("Names").ToString().Replace("," "<br />") %>'
```